# How can I solve $\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}(\arctan\left(\frac{8}{15}\right)\right)$ using the cosine Half Angle Identity?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, analytic-geometry

$\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}(\arctan\left(\frac{8}{15}\right)\right)$ is the same as $\cos(A/2)$ if $A= \arctan\left(\frac{8}{15}\right)$. Using this, how can I evaluate this with the Cosine Half Angle Identity?

I know that $\tan(x)= \frac{8}{15}$, so $\cos x =15$. From here I used the identity: $\sqrt{(1+15)/2}$, but the answer is not $\sqrt{8}$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I know that tan(x)= 8/15, so cos x =15. From here I used the identity: sqrt((1+15)/2), but the answer is not sqrt(8)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include your thoughts. (Follow the link.)

Comment: Are you sure about $\cos x=15$? Maybe a certain property regarding the possible output values (the range) of the cosine function would give you a hint that you're doing something wrong?

Comment: You're right, cosine can be from -1 to 1. Then how else can I get a value for cos(x)?

Comment: $\arctan(8/15)$ is an angle in a right-angled triangle with catheti $8$ and $15$, where $8$ is the cathetus opposite to the angle. Then the hypotenuse has length $17$. You need to divide this angle in half. You can use the [angle bisector theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem) to compute the dimensions of the right-angled triangle formed when you bisect the angle. If $x$ is the cathetus of the new right-angled triangle then $\frac{15}{17}=\frac{x}{8-x}$. Therefore, $x=15/4$. Therefore, the new hypotenuse is $\frac{15\sqrt{17}}{4}$. Therefore, the cosine is $4/\sqrt{17}$

Comment: @cactus Your comment merits posting as an answer.  As someone pointed out me, when we answer questions with the comment, the question still shows up as unanswered.  BTW, "cathetus" and "catheti" were new words to me -- thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cosine half angle formula is a good idea, but you need to get at $\cos A$. Start from $\cos^2A+\sin^2A=1$. Dividing by $\cos^2A$, you get
$$
1+\tan^2A=\frac{1}{\cos^2A}
$$
that implies
$$
\cos^2A=\frac{1}{1+\tan^2A}
$$
Since you know that $\tan A=8/15$, you can deduce
$$
\cos^2A=\frac{1}{1+\dfrac{8^2}{15^2}}=\frac{15^2}{289}=\frac{15^2}{17^2}
$$
On the other hand, $A$ is an acute angle, because $0<\arctan x<\pi/2$, for $x>0$. Hence $\cos A>0$ and we can deduce
$$
\cos A=\frac{15}{17}
$$
Now we can apply the half angle formuls:
$$
\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos A}{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{1+(15/17)}{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{16}{17}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

If   $\frac {A}{B}=\tan x=\frac {\sin x}{\cos x}$ then we can write $\sin x=At$ and $\cos x=Bt$ for some $t.$ Then $1=\sin^2x+\cos^2 x=(A^2+B^2)t^2 .$ So $|t|=\frac {1}{\sqrt {A^2+B^2}}.$ So $$|\sin x| = |At|=\frac {|A|}{\sqrt {A^2+B^2}}$$  and $$|cos x|=|Bt|=\frac {|B|}{\sqrt {A^2+B^2}}.$$

The function $\arctan$ is (usually) defined to take values in $[-\pi/2.\pi/2].$

Let $x=\arctan \frac {8}{15}.$ Then $x\in (0,\pi/2)$  so both $\cos x$ and $\cos  \frac {x}{2}$ are positive.

With $A=8$ and $B=15$ and $\cos x>0$ we have $\cos x= \frac {15}{\sqrt {8^2+15^2}\;}= \frac {15}{17}.$

Therefore $$\cos \left(\frac {1}{2}\arctan \frac {8}{15}\right)= \cos  \frac {1}{2}x=\sqrt {\frac {1+\cos x}{2}}\;=$$ $$=\sqrt {   \frac{1+15/17}{2}\;}=\frac {4}{\sqrt {17}\;}.$$